# What will $( "li", "li.item-ii" ) do?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This might be a noob question buy Will $( "li", "li.item-ii" ) select all li's and the li.item-ii inside the '' or select only li's which are descendants of li.item-ii ?

```
    <body>
       <ul class="level-1">
       <li class="item-i">I&lt; /li&gt;</li>

       <li class="item-ii">II

        <ul class="level-2">
        <li class="item-a">A</li>

         <li class="item-b">B

        <ul class="level-3">
         <li class="item-1">1</li>

         <li class="item-2">2</li>

         <li class="item-3">3</li>
       </ul>
        </li>

      <li class="item-c">C</li>
      </ul>
      </li>

     <li class="item-iii">III</li>
     </ul>
      </body>
```

Comment: Why don't *you* try it and tell *us*?

Comment: The second argument expected would be the context, you have to supply it as a single string though.

Comment: `$ === jQuery` The document for the `jQuery` function is here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery Please read documentation to find out how the API works.

Comment: isn't the syntax of context selection and multiple selection same?

will $('item1','item2') slect all item1's and item2's OR will it select item1's which are descendants of item2?

Comment: The documentation for multiple selection is here: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/ The documentation for the `jQuery` function is in my comment above. Read them to learn the difference.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can eliminate the class names in every LI because you can reference the UL element's immediate LI children. For example:

```
var $cLi1 = $("ul.level-1 > li") //returns collection of the UL element's immediate LI children
```

You don't even really need class names on the 2nd-level UL and LI elements because you can use CSS syntax to reference them. For example:

```
//2nd level
var $cLi2 = $("ul.level-1 > li > ul > li") //returns collection of LI elements in 2nd level UL elements

//3rd level
var $cLi3 = $("ul.level-1 > li > ul > li > ul > li")

//if you want to find elements within a jQuery object, both of these work the same:
var $ul1 = $("ul.level-1");
var $cLi1 = $ul1.find("> li")
//or
var $cLi1 = $("> li", $ul1);
```

For a comprehensive reference of jQuery selectors, visit: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is called context. It's the same as
`$('li.item-ii').find('li')`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, This is called scoped search `$( "li", "li.item-ii" )`;

it means it will find all li tags which are inside of `li.item-ii`.

if there is too much html in your page, then this will help to improve performance.

Another method:

`$("li.item-ii").find("li")`.

this mehtod also gives the same result as `$( "li", "li.item-ii" )`

Comment: but isn't $(item1,item2) used for selecting item 1 and item 2 and not all item1's inside the item2?

Comment: for multiple selection `$("li,li.item-ii")` is used

Comment: @PradeepSaini To clarify: the second argument of jQuery's `$()` function is a context argument for the search, see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Answer (score 0):

It'll only return all the li under the li with class="item-ii"

And if you want to access all the li you should try:-

```
$( "li" );
```

Answer (score 0):

`$( "li", "li.item-ii" )` - this jQuery selector points two different elements.

- First `$("li")` - selects all the `li`(s) in the provided html.
- Second `$("li.item-ii")` - selects all the second `li` and it's child elements.

Now if these are being used together then `$("li", "li.item-ii")` selector will select all the `li`(s) into the provided html.

So this is all. Hope this will help you much! Cheers!